# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

any solution for this error

> AttributeError at /api/register/
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
> Request Method: POST
> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/register/
> Django Version: 3.1.2
> Python Executable: /opt/anaconda3/envs/catermahalENV/bin/python
> Python Version: 3.8.8
> Python Path: ['/Users/saifulazam/Desktop/Clients/Catermahal/catermahal', '/opt/anaconda3/envs/catermahalENV/lib/python38.zip', '/opt/anaconda3/envs/catermahalENV/lib/python3.8', '/opt/anaconda3/envs/catermahalENV/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/opt/anaconda3/envs/catermahalENV/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
> Server time: Thu, 13 May 2021 05:57:19 +0000

serializers.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'email', 'password')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data['name'], validated_data['email'], validated_data['password'])

        return user
```

views.py

```
class RegisterAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()

        return Response({
            "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
            'token': AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]
        })
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

You show `POST` handler in your view and its serializer but your error message says `GET`.